# What's the Python equivalent of x = (10<n) ? 10 : n;

Tags: python, ternary

I was wondering what the equivalent in python to this would be:

```
n = 100
x = (10 < n) ? 10 : n;
print x;
```

For some reason this does not work in Python. I know I can use an if statement but I was just curious if there is some shorter syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: What made you think that `?` and `:` formed a legal operator in Python?  Where have you seen code like that?  What tutorial are you using?

Comment: I have not; I was basing this on JavaScript syntax;

Answer (score 17):

```
x = min(n, 10)
```

Or, more generally:

```
x = 10 if 10<n else n
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Python) in Python (also know as [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in the docs).

```
x if cond else y
```

Comment: +1 for answering the more helpful yet unasked question about ternary operators in Python.

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways to make a ternary operation, the first one is the expression added with 2.5:

```
n = foo if condition else bar
```

If you want to be compatible with versions lower than 2.5 you can exploit the fact that booleans are subclasses from `int` and that `True` behaves like `1` whereas `False` behaves like `0`:

```
n = [bar, foo][condition]
```

Another possibility is to exploit the way operators in Python behave or more exactly how `and` and `or` behave:

```
n = condition and foo or bar
```

Comment: I like the first and last methods you used, but the middle one wouldn't be immediately obvious to most people reading your code. I find your last method interesting, because it's exactly the same as the `? :` syntax, but with the symbols replaced with `and` and `or`, and it's not hard to read if you understand how `and` and `or` work

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> n = 100
>>> x = 10 if n > 10 else n
>>> x
10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
10 if 10 < n else n
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 10 if (10 < n) else n
```

(requires python 2.5)